# creating duplicate entries in db error in rails, likely form submission error

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, duplicates

hello im creating a favorites feature but its creating duplicate ids in the db. it stores the id correctly but it duplicates the entry.

in my favorite form i have...

```
<div id="favorite_form">
    <% if current_user.favorited?(@lesson) %>
      <%= render 'unfavorite' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'favorite' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

and my favorite partial is...

```
<%= puts "xx favorite partial"%>
<%= form_for(current_user.favorite_relationships.build(lesson_id: @lesson.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :lesson_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Favorite", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

which should be calling my FavoriteRelationships#create when the user clicks on the favorite button

```
def create
    puts "xx create"
    puts params[:favorite_relationship][:lesson_id]
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:favorite_relationship][:lesson_id])
    current_user.favorite!(@lesson) 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson }
        format.js
    end
end
```

in the code above, i call my user model function favorite! which looks like...

```
  def favorite!(lesson)
    puts 'xx favorite'
    favorite_relationships.create!(lesson_id: lesson.id)
  end
```

i put print statements and for some reason...'xx create' gets called twice and so does 'xx favorite'. the partial gets rendered once, which is correct because 'xx favorite partial' only appears once. however my FavoritesRelationships#create is being called twice

what is going on?

in my lesson model, which is what the user is trying to favorite i have..

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorite_relationships
  has_many :users, :through => :favorite_relationships
```

and in my user model i have

```
  has_many :lessons
  has_many :favorite_relationships
```

the favorites feature is only one part of the web app, which is why i have more than one association.

lastly but not least i have in my favorite_relationship.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
```

i dont think its an association problem but it could be thats why i pasted the code anyway.

what is going wrong? help would be appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it. something was corrupt and i had to do

```
rake assets:clean
```